# Why does not Map key type work when extracted from a case class?

Tags: scala, dictionary, types

In following code, the map key can be used directly or when stored in a `val`, but not when stored in a `case class`:

```
sealed trait FooKey
case object KeyA extends FooKey
case object KeyB extends FooKey

case class KaseKey(key:FooKey)

object Main extends App {
  val m = Map(KeyA -> "A", KeyB -> "B")


  val kk = KaseKey(KeyA)
  val kv = KeyA

  m(KeyA) // works
  m(kv) // works
  m(kk.key) // error: found: Main.kk.key.type (with underlying type FooKey)
}
```

The full error shown for the last line is:

> Error:(16, 8) type mismatch;
>
> found   : Main.kk.key.type (with underlying type FooKey)
>
> required: Product with Serializable with FooKey

What is the reason for this? Why is the key no longer accepted and fails a type check once stored in a `case class`?

Comment: Some compiler stuff here. `val m : Map[FooKey, String] = Map(KeyA -> "A", KeyB -> "B") m(kk.key)` seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the key's type inferred by the following line:

```
val m = Map(KeyA -> "A", KeyB -> "B")
```

If you look at the REPL, it will tell you that it sees `Map[Product with Serializable with FooKey,String]`. This is because the common super-type of `KeyA` and `KeyB` is just that. Case classes give you the `Product` trait that allows iteration over the product elements, defines `equals` and `hashCode`.

So you should annotate your map:

```
val m = Map[FooKey, String](KeyA -> "A", KeyB -> "B")
```

Alternatively you define

```
sealed trait FooKey extends Product with Serializable
```

Comment: There is one more alternative, I can ascribe one of the keys to eliminate `Product` from possible key type:`val m = Map((KeyA:FooKey) -> "A", KeyB -> "B")`

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? In Scala 2.11, both case classes and case objects _do_ implement `Product`.

Comment: As a trait, `FooKey` is abstract by definition and does not need to implement anything.

Comment: You are correct. I mistook it for a `sealed class` (which has shown the same behaviour with my original example).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030276/16673) by [0__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515054/0), this is because as a result of using `case objects` for the map keys the type of `m` is inferred not as `FooKey`, but as `Product with Serializable with FooKey`.

One could avoid this by using plain `objects` instead of `case objects`:

```
sealed trait FooKey
object KeyA extends FooKey
object KeyB extends FooKey
```

One possible drawback is a [default Java Object hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) is used, which may be less reasonable than the one provided by the `case objects`.

Comment: So briefly, the right approach is to specify the key type explicitly as `FooKey`